# $a - b, b-c, c-d$ form a basis for this kernel.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Hatcher P99 last paragraph:

> Define a homomorphism $\partial: C_1 \to C_0$ by sending each basis element $a,b,c,d$ to $y-x$, the vertex at the head of the edge minus the vertex at the tail. Thus $$\partial (ka + lb + mc + nd) = (k + l + m + n)y - (k + l + m + n)x,$$
>   and the cycles are precisely the kernel of $\partial$, and $a - b, b-c, c-d$ form a basis for this kernel.

But I can't see how $a - b, b-c, c-d$ form a basis for the kernel? I tried to show that $$r_1(a-b) + r_2(b-c) + r_3(c-d) = 0,$$
but it won't come out?

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

First, in that example $\;C_1\cong\Bbb Z^4\;$ = the free abelian group of rank $\;4\;$ , and it's clear that $\;\partial(C_1)\cong\Bbb Z\;$ , so by the first isomorphism theorem

$$C_1/\ker\partial\cong\partial(C_1)\cong\Bbb Z\implies \ker\partial\cong\Bbb Z^3$$

and we're indeed looking for three free (abelian) generators.

Now, as written there, we have that

$$ka+lb+mc+nd\in\ker\partial\iff k+l+m+n=0\implies\;\;\text{we can actually write:}$$

$$ka+lb+mc+nd=\alpha(a-b)+\beta(b-c)+\gamma(c-d)=\alpha a+(\beta-\alpha)b+(\gamma-\beta)c-\gamma d$$

$$\iff \begin{align*}k&=\alpha\\l&=\beta-\alpha\\m&=\gamma-\beta\\n&=-\gamma\end{align*}\iff\begin{cases}\alpha=k\\\beta=k+l\\\gamma=-n\end{cases}$$

For example:

$$3a-5b-2c+4d=3(a-b)-2(b-c)-4(c-d)$$

Comment: Thank you Don, here's what I don't understand: I understand the kernel of $\partial$ as loops going in and out of $x$ and $y$ for the same amount of time, that is paths coming in to $x$ (that is $k+ l + m +n$) is the same as $y$ (that is $k+ l + m +n$)?

Comment: @1LiterTears Yes

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't specifically answer why $a-b, b-c, c-d$ form a basis, however, I think there is a nicer and easier way to see that a basis consists of three similar elements, namely: $$a-b, a-c, a-d.$$

---

First, those elements map to $0$ by definition of $\partial$. So, all are in $\ker \partial$.

Next, as written in the book: if $\partial (ka+\ell b+mc+nd)=0$, then $k+\ell+m+n=0$. So, just write $k=-\ell-m-n$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
ka+\ell b + mc +nd &= (-\ell -m-n)a+\ell b +mc +nd\\
&= -\ell(a-b)-m(a-c)-n(a-d).
\end{align*}
So, $ka+\ell b + mc +nd \in \langle a-b, a-c, a-d \rangle$.
Therefore, $$\ker \partial = \langle a-b, a-c, a-d \rangle.$$